# AIR(Flex) local socket connection

Tags: c++, apache-flex, air, sockets, local

When connecting from a local AIR/Flex application to a local application (c++) using sockets do you still need a socket policy file?  If you do, is there an easy way to load the policy file without sending the policy from the local application you are trying to connect to?  side note: I am writing both applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to another application on the localhost using sockets, you do not need to use a socket policy.